# What is the cost of inheritance in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, inheritance

I have two classes that are nearly the same - they have differences in a few methods.
I was wondering if it is a good idea to make one class extend the other and override these methods or to create if conditions and stick to only one class.
Is inheritance costly and worth using in Kotlin or maybe is there another way to solve my issue?

Comment: Are the similarities by coincidence or are they structural? If they are by coincidence, I would not recommend "merging" them by inheritance since inheritance means coupling.

Comment: One is a slight extension from the other thats why my initial thought was to use inheritance. But for the sake of memory usage and/or performance I was thinking if that is too costly, hence the question.

Comment: Do you have an actual memory usage and/or performance problem? Remember that ["*premature optimization is the root of all evil*" -- Donald Ervin Knuth: *Computer Programming as an Art* (1974), p. 671](https://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=361612&ftid=289767)

Comment: Not really, was just curious if either of two is more or less affected by this. And you're absolutely right, fixing not existing problems is a vicious circle.